# ListView padding on last item

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a `ListView`defined in a `Grid` like this:

```
<Border BorderThickness="1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,50" BorderBrush="Gray">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <TextBlock Text="Test" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
    <ListView 
        Grid.Row="1"
        ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"
        Padding="40,40,40,40"/>
  </Grid>
```

My problem is that I want the last item of the listview to be 40 pixel away from listView's bottom, but my code is not working, the top padding is ok, but bottom has no effect. That is like adding a blank item on the beginning and the end of the listview but that would be a stupid thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the ListView inside of another Scrollviewer and pad the ListView itself.